# How do I make an http request response useful with Clojure?

Tags: clojurescript

The response I get when making an http request JavaScript is usually an array of objects after parsing the data. With ClojureScript I get a very complex data structure back after making a request with the [cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http) library. The docs say that it returns a `core.async channel`, so my first question is how do I parse that in to data I can map over? Here's the top level view of my response:

[image]

Here's my code:

```clj
(defn getFileTree []
  (def API-URL "x")
  (go (let [response (<! (http/get API-URL
                                   {:with-credentials? false
                                    :headers {"Content-Type" "application/json"}}))]
        (js/console.log (:status response))
        (js/console.log (:body response)))))
```

My second question is, say if I call the function `getFileTree` from another namespace like this:

```clj
(def res (api/getFileTree))
  (js/console.log res)
```

and want `res` to directly resolve to the response of the http request, how do I do that? At the moment it looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Ok thanks @Carcigenicate, but as you can see from the images the response has been handled, I have the response, it's just not in any kind of format that's useable unless I do something to it? Do you know if I need to destructure it? I'm getting status 200 and I can see some properties of the json deeply nested in this object.

Answer (score 0):

The `go` block [returns a channel](http://clojure.github.io/core.async/#clojure.core.async/go). You have a couple options:

#### 1. Read from that channel with `<!` in another `go` block

```
(go (js/console.log (<! api/getFileTree)))
```

#### 2. Pass a callback with `take!`

```
(take! api/getFileTree js/console.log)
```

---

You might be tempted to:

#### 3. Block with `<!!` to get the result in the current thread.

```
(js/console.log (<!! api/getFileTree))
```

But this is not available in ClojureScript because [javascript is single-threaded](https://medium.com/techtrument/multithreading-javascript-46156179cf9a) so [blocking causes the page to hang](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Synchronous_and_Asynchronous_Requests#Synchronous_request).